# Photoshop scripting. Get image dimensions to clipboard

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting

Often I save lots of versions of the same image with different dimensions so I usually include them in filename. It pisses me off to go and check dimensions for every document before saving it so I'd love to automate this. I need a script that gets document dimensions and copies them to clipboard in 000x000 format so I can paste them in "Save as" dialog. Two scripts: In pixels or millimeters.
I'm in the process of learning to script myself but it takes time. And I badly want this script right now :) Please help!
Thanks a lot!

Comment: why not just directly rename the document with that info? why bother with pasting. On that note why not handle all scalings at the same time?

Comment: @joojaa Because in most cases document hasn't been saved yet. And in most cases it's not simple scaling, it's the same layout in different versions, different proportions etc.

Comment: unsaved documents can have placeholder names, anyway clipboard actions are a bit complex in jsx.

Comment: Can you test my solution out and let me know if it works for what you're doing.

Comment: "it pisses me off to go and check dimensions for every document..." lol.

Answer (score 3):

Eureka! This script will use active document's width and height as the file name and open the save dialog box with the file name preset for you. Choose a folder and save.

```
var saveOptions = new JPEGSaveOptions( );  
saveOptions.embedColorProfile = true;  
saveOptions.formatOptions = FormatOptions.STANDARDBASELINE;  
saveOptions.matte = MatteType.NONE;  
saveOptions.quality = 12; // image quality (0,12)
var w = app.activeDocument.width.toString().replace(' px', '');
var h = app.activeDocument.height.toString().replace(' px', '');
var file = new File(w + 'x' + h + '.jpg');
var filePath = file.saveDlg("Select Folder");
var saved = app.activeDocument.saveAs( filePath, saveOptions, true );
```

**How to implement:**

- Save as widthXheight.jsx
- Paste file in your Presets\Scripts folder
- Reload Photoshop
- with a file open, click File > Scripts > widthXheight

Comment: You probably need a external app for the clipboard action before cs6- creative cloud see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066108/photoshop-jsx-how-do-i-copy-arbitrary-text-to-the-clipboard for clipboard actions. I dont have cs 6 at home

Comment: Yeah, I hit a wall on that so I just propagated the file name instead, negating the need for a clipboard and saving a step in the questioneer's process =)

Comment: Sure thats what i proposed, anyway presumably in newer PSes it works, cant test like i said no PS CC or cs6 at home

Comment: Ah I just saw that, it wasn't so obvious for me haha

Comment: NP this is the better, clipboard is a extra step unless the OP needs some others stuff hes not saying, solution loose the double dot tough. (also if you script listen you can move the cursor to the front of the name saving a click, as far as i seem to recall)

Comment: Fixed the extra dot, thanks! Not sure I know how to do what you're describing on the last part.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16373/discussion-between-joojaa-and-brian).

Comment: @Brian Thanks a lot! I'll try it tonight in CC 2014 and let you know.

Comment: No problem. Yeah, let me know if it works for you/your setup & Ill tweak if need be

Comment: will this work on older versions?

Comment: @expiredninja, not sure.. maybe try it out and let future readers now. I tested on CS6